# Prove a recursive formula for the number of walks of length $2n$ with given start and end vertex in a $W_4$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

The number of walks in a $W_4$ with start vertex $v_1$ and end vertex $v_2$ can be calculated by the recursive formula $a_n = 2 a_{n − 1} + 4 a_{n − 2}$, where $a_0 = 0$ and $a_1=1$.

[image]

**My approach:** I started to use induction.

*Base:* a$_2 = 2a_1 + 4$ $a_0 \implies  a_2 = 2$ is true. ($\{v_1,v_5,v_2\}$ and $\{v_1,v_3,v_2\}$).

Assume that $a_k = 2a_{k−1} + 4a_{k−2}$   , for $k>2$ is true.

I do not know, how to show the inductive step $a_{k+1} = 2a_κ + 4a_{k−1}$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://www.onemathematicalcat.org/MathJaxDocumentation/TeXSyntax.htm) to format your posts.  To begin with, surround math expressions (including numbers) with `$` signs and use `_` for subscripts.  `$x_1$` comes out as $x_1$.

Comment: Thus an = 2an−1 + 4an−2 = 6an - 3:  3 = 5an.  Do you mean a_n =  2a_(n - 1) + 4a_(n - 3)?